# Preserving datetime index in groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame (timeseries, first column is a DateTimeIndex)

```
                           atn   file
datetime                             
2012-10-08 14:00:00  23.007462      1
2012-10-08 14:30:00  27.045666      1
2012-10-08 15:00:00  31.483825      1
2012-10-08 15:30:00  37.540651      2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  43.564573      2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  48.589852      2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  55.289452      2
```

My **goal** is to to extract the rows with the first appearance of a certain number in the last column 'file', so **to obtain a table similar to this**:

```
       datetime             atn
file                             
1      2012-10-08 14:00:00  23.007462
2      2012-10-08 15:30:00  37.540651
```

My **approach** was to groupby 'file' and then aggregate on 'first':

```
dt.groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")
```

But the problem with this is that then the index is not used as a column which is grouped. I solved this by first adding the index as a column by:

```
dt2 = dt.reset_index()
dt2.groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")
```

But now the **problem** is that the datetime column aren't dates anymore but floats:

```
          datetime        atn
file                         
1     1.349705e+18  23.007462
2     1.349710e+18  37.540651
```

Is there

- a way to convert the floats back to a datetime?
- OR a way to preserve the datetimes in the groupby/aggregate-operation?
- OR a better way to achieve this the final tabel?

---

The example dataframe can be used as follows:

Copy this (to clipboard):

```
2012-10-08 14:00:00,  23.007462,     1
2012-10-08 14:30:00,  27.045666,     1
2012-10-08 15:00:00,  31.483825,     1
2012-10-08 15:30:00,  37.540651,     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00,  43.564573,     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00,  48.589852,     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00,  55.289452,     2
```

And then:

```
dt = pandas.read_clipboard(sep=",", parse_dates=True, index_col=0, 
                           names=["datetime", "atn", "file"])
```

Comment: which version of pandas are you using? I am getting `dt2` following your process with the datetime appropriately preserved.

Comment: And maybe also important, my numpy version (datetime64 related things): >>> pandas.__version__
'0.9.0'
>>> np.__version__
'1.6.1'

Comment: Ok. `parse_dates` seem to be the problem @joris. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a bug in pandas - the dtype is changed to a float after the groupby

```
dt3 = dt2.groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")
dt3.dtypes
```

Gives me:

```
datetime    float64
atn         float64
```

To change the dtype back to datetime64 you can do:

```
dt3['datetime'] = pd.Series(dt3['datetime'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I have created a new issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2238)

Comment: looks ok on master: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2238#issuecomment-10327256

Comment: Thanks! Change it back to datetime64 as you pointed out is a good solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug but at this moment, **not specifying** `parse_dates=True` will give me the expected result.

My ipython results - no `parse_dates=True`:-

```
In [29]: dt2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", index_col=0, 
                           names=["datetime", "atn", "file"])

In [30]: dt2
Out[30]: 
                           atn  file
datetime                            
2012-10-08 14:00:00  23.007462     1
2012-10-08 14:30:00  27.045666     1
2012-10-08 15:00:00  31.483825     1
2012-10-08 15:30:00  37.540651     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  43.564573     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  48.589852     2
2012-10-08 16:00:00  55.289452     2

In [31]: dt2.reset_index().groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")
Out[31]: 
                 datetime        atn
file                                
1     2012-10-08 14:00:00  23.007462
2     2012-10-08 15:30:00  37.540651

In [32]:
```

My ipython results, with `parse_dates=True`:-

```
In [33]: dt = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", parse_dates=True, index_col=0, 
                           names=["datetime", "atn", "file"])
KeyboardInterrupt

In [33]: dt = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", parse_dates=True, index_col=0, 
                           names=["datetime", "atn", "file"])

In [34]: dt.reset_index().groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")
Out[34]: 
          datetime        atn
file                         
1     1.349705e+18  23.007462
2     1.349710e+18  37.540651
```

Explicitly checking `dtypes`:-

```
In [40]: new_dt = dt.reset_index().groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")

In [41]: new_dt
Out[41]: 
          datetime        atn
file                         
1     1.349705e+18  23.007462
2     1.349710e+18  37.540651

In [42]: new_dt.dtypes
Out[42]: 
datetime    float64
atn         float64

In [43]: new_dt2 = dt2.reset_index().groupby(by="file").aggregate("first")

In [44]: new_dt2.dtypes
Out[44]: 
datetime     object
atn         float64
```

Comment: Not specifying 'parse_dates=True' will result in an index of dtype object, it will hold strings. There is no DatatimeIndex in this case!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need it to still be a datetime for my further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is fixed and will be in 0.9.1 release